# What should the standard contents of $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH be?

Tags: xcode, command-line

I'm trying to install [CERN's root libraries](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) on my mac os Lion.

It needs me to set `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but on checking

```
echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

it seems to be empty (before I'm adding to it). Is this normal?

What are `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`'s default contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked on clean installs of Lion at 10.7.3 and 10.7.3 with server and both have the $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable unset. Installing Xcode doesn't change that variable either on the current OS.